# Cannot convert System.String to class type

Tags: c#

I'm working with Polymorphism and I've run into a problem.

What I want to do is to call Animal class method `GetEaterType()` when list item is selected but I can't convert the animal class to `Resultlst.SelectedItem;`
This is how I tried:

```
private void Resultlst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Animal theanimal = (Animal) Resultlst.SelectedItem;
            // EaterTypetxt.Text = theanimal.GetEaterType().ToString();
        }
```

When I select an item on the list, I get error

> "Failed to convert an object of type System.String the type
>   Assign_1.Animal"

**UPDATE**: How I populate the `Resultlst` with data

```
 private void UpdateResults()
        {
            Resultlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list
            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.ElementCount; index++)
            {
                Animal animal = animalmgr.GetElementAtPosition(index);

                //Adds to the list.
               Resultlst.Items.Add(animal.ToString());

            }
```

Comment: Show code for `Animal` class including its `ToString` implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `ToString()` on your `Animal` when you add it to the list.

Use the `DisplayMember` property on the `ListBox` to specify which property of the `Animal` class should be displayed to the user.

```
for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.ElementCount; index++)
{
    Animal animal = animalmgr.GetElementAtPosition(index);

    Resultlst.Items.Add(animal);   // add the Animal instance; don't call ToString()
}

Resultlst.DisplayMember = "Name";  // whatever property of your class is appropriate
```

Now you can cast the `SelectedItem` property to an `Animal`.

```
private void Resultlst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Animal theanimal = (Animal)Resultlst.SelectedItem;

    EaterTypetxt.Text = theanimal.GetEaterType().ToString();
}
```

Since you've got multiple properties you'd like to display (which is why you're using `ToString()` in the first place), you could add a property to your class with just a "getter", and reference that:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Color.Name, Name); }  // Red Dog, Purple Unicorn
    }
}

Resultlst.DisplayMember = "Description";
```

---

Addendum.. if you want to make the `Description` property overridable in derived classes, just make it virtual and override it when you want to:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Color.Name, Name); }
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override string Description
    {
        get { return base.Description; }
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public override string Description
    {
        get { return "I'm a cat. I'm special."; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is all assuming that his Resultlst class is of type `Animal` and not of type string.

Comment: But it's not just one property that I want to display on the list. It's lots of them and `ToString` is spacing them up nicely.
Is there no other way to call child class by using Polymorphism?

Comment: @GrantWinney Can't I just call it `Resultlst.DisplayMember = "ToString";`?

Comment: @GrantWinney But can the Description property that you mentioned be overwritten by child classes?

Comment: @Kevin.A - yes, declare it as `public virtual string Description ...`